# How do I change the Status labels in Bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

I don't want to change how the Status field works I just want to change the labels to
the states that the old system uses.  (the old systems consists of spreadsheets and paper :P

We are using 3.0

```
* UNCONFIRMED  --> PRELIMARY
* NEW          --> DESIGN REVIEW
* ASSIGNED     --> STR1
* RESOLVED     --> STR2
* REOPEN
* VERIIFED     --> BMR
* CLOSED       --> TCG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done by modifying the templates look here:

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.22/html/cust-templates.html

specifically:
**global/variables.none.tmpl**

Answer (score 3):

If you log into the bugzilla system as an administrator you'll see on the bottom a link that says "Field Values", click that, on the next page you'll see "Resolution", go there then click on the resolution you'd like to change,

Comment: I want to change the Status not the resolution

Comment: @Sally Status are also available from that link. This is an easier way than editing templates